# How to reset state variable value to its initial value always when a component is rendered in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component which is like a graph where you can click on different nodes to get additional info. I have a boolean state variable (**clickedNode**) in this component to determine if I need to render another component (basically tables with info) when a node is clicked. So from this graph component, I'm calling this table component and in the table component I have another state variable (**clickedTableRow**). Basically, I want this state variable to initialize to false always when this table component is rendered. I have some logic which sets this variable to true in table component but how can I initialize this variable to false always when table component is called from the graph component?

For reference, this is the template for my code:

```
  const Graph=()=>{

    //graph rendering code

    {clickedNode?(<div> <Table /> </div>):("")}

  }

  const Table = props => {

    let[clickedTableRow,setTableRowClicked]=useState(false)  // I want clickedTableRow to be initialized to false always

    //rest of the table code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular variable instead of state: let clickedTableRow = false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).